# Jquery slick is not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, slick.js

I need to display set of images using slick jquery plugin.
Here I am using ng-repeat for get set of images.
my jquery code is:

```
$('.multiple-items').slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
        arrows:true,
        responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: true,
            dots: true
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 600,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    });
```

My view code:

```
<div class="smilar_cars">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="btm_slider">
                                <div class="slider multiple-items">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="model in similarModels">
                                        <div class="car_info">
                                            <div class="car_img">
                                                <img src="/Content/Models/{{model.ModelBigImage}}" alt="" />
                                            </div>
                                            <h3>{{model.ManufacturerName}}</h3>
                                            <h2>&pound;{{model.BusinessPrice}}</h2>
                                            <span class="tag">Model: {{model.ModelName}}</span>
                                            <span class="details_link no_bg">
                                                <a href="/Deal/{{model.ModelName}}">DETAILS</a>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Angular controller code:

```
app.controller('BaseController', ['$scope', '$http','$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.bannerIds = [];
    $scope.similarModels = [];
    $scope.getManufacturerList = function () {

        $http.get('/Home/GetManufacturerList').success(function (response) {
            $scope.manufacturerList = response;
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

    $scope.getBanners = function () {
        $http.get('/Home/GetBanners').success(function (response) {
            $scope.banners = response;
            angular.forEach($scope.banners, function (value, key) {
                $scope.bannerIds.push(value.ModelID);
            });
            $http.get('/Home/GetSimilarModelsofBanners', { params: { 'id': $scope.bannerIds } })
          .success(function (response) {              
              $scope.similarModels = response;
              console.log($scope.similarModels);
          })
          .error(function (data) {
              console.log(data);
          });
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });       
    }


}]);
```

in this,i need to display the $scope.similarModels data.
if I am display without ng-repeat, slick is working fine.
anyone have any idea what is wrong in this?

Comment: Can you post your Angular controller code?

Comment: Use **https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick** instead, trying to use a jQuery plugin along with `ng-repeat` or similar is doomed to fail.

Comment: Sorry, we can't use that angular slick. because, it is asking to install bower. instead of this, is there any other options to fix this.

Comment: You can go to the angular-slick repo and just copy or download the code from dist/slick.min.js. The plug-in is registered with Bower but that's not the only way to get it

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code needs to run in the `success` callback for your `GetSimilarModelsofBanners` call. But even then, once $scope.similarModels is defined, you need to give Angular some time to render the DOM elements that Slick uses. So inject $timeout and inside the `success` callback have a timed-out function to initialize Slick.

```
$timeout(function () {
    $('.multiple-items').slick(params);
});
```

Running $timeout() without a time set makes it wait until the digest is done running (rendering the ng-repeat items in this case).

...is my best guess. If you throw this into a jsfiddle it would be easier to say for certain.

Comment: Oh my god so much headache was saved with this comment, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it work with me.

```js
angular.module([sth]).directive('slick', function ($timeout) {
    return function (scope, sample, attrs) {
        $timeout((function () {
            sample.slick({
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                arrows: false,
                dots: true,
                infinite: true,
            })
        }), 100)
    }
})
```

```xml
<slick init-onload="true">
    <div ng-repeat="image in imageTest">
        <img ng-src="{{image.imageURL}}">
    </div>
</slick>
```